# Why Chinese Remainder Theorem(CRT) will give unique $x \bmod M$?

Tags: number-theory

If the $m_1, ..., m_r$ are pairwise coprime, and if $a_1, \ldots, a_r$ are any integers, then system of $r$ conqruences

$$x \equiv a_ i \bmod m_ i   \text{($ 1\le i \le r$)}$$

has a unique solution modulo $M= m_1 \times m_2 \times.... \times m_r$, which is given by

$$x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}\space a_iM_i y_i \bmod M,$$

where $M_i = \frac{M}{m_i}$ and $y_i =M_i^{-1} \bmod m_i$ for $ 1\le i \le r$.

Could you please explain CRT will give unique $x \bmod M$?

Comment: Because .... that's what the statement of CRT claims????  Go through the proof of CRT.  That will tell you why the CRT is true.

Answer (score 3):

Let x, y be integers both satisfying all those congruences.

Then $x\equiv a_i\equiv y\pmod {m_i}$ for every $i$.

Hence, $m_i$ divides $x-y$ for every $i$.

Since $m_1,\dots, m_r$ are pairwise coprime then...

Try to fill the gap.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of a unique solution follows directly by considering the kernel of the natural map
$$
\mathbb Z
\to
\mathbb Z / m_1 \mathbb Z \times \cdots \times \mathbb Z / m_r \mathbb Z
$$
given by 
$$
x  \mapsto (x \bmod m_1, \dots, x \bmod m_r)
$$